# Any reason for not getting rid of bash dependency in rpm?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rpm, dependencies, yocto

I don't want `bash` in my yocto image, but it got included over a couple of dependencies. I was able to get rid of most of them, now only the `rpm` is left (which I need).

Tracking it down I found only two scripts

- [rpmdb_loadcvt](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/debian/jessie/main/amd64/rpm/4.11.3-1.1/file/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_loadcvt)
- [pythondeps.sh](https://www.apt-browse.org/browse/debian/jessie/main/amd64/rpm/4.11.3-1.1/file/usr/lib/rpm/pythondeps.sh)

that have a `#!/bin/bash` shebang for no obvious reason. Writing a `bbappend` to patch the interpreter line of those two scripts and removing the `RDEPEND`ency successfully `bitbake`s an image which works (including rpm packet installation).

But it still feels uncomfortable, because there could have been a reason for somebody to explicitly request a `bash` for the scripts. Shellcheck.net has enough warnings, but none about POSIX incompatibility.

Can you see a reason for not removing `bash` dependency that simple way?

Comment: Why do you need RPM? The packages you install might have maintainer scripts that might use bash.

Comment: rpmdb_loadcvt is a pretty bad shell script. No variable quoting, using `ls` to generate a list of files... I may be prejudiced, but I doubt that someone who wirtes shell scripts like that knows enough about shell scripting to know that bash is actually required. I would guess they just defaulted to bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out there were more dependencies to remove in the end. My final patch `recipes-devtools/rpm/files/0001-remove-bash-dependency.patch` looks like:

```
--- a/scripts/rpmdb_loadcvt
+++ b/scripts/rpmdb_loadcvt
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
 
 ac=$#
 cmd=`basename $0`
--- a/scripts/pythondeps.sh
+++ b/scripts/pythondeps.sh
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
 
 [ $# -ge 1 ] || {
     cat > /dev/null

--- a/scripts/pkgconfigdeps.sh
+++ b/scripts/pkgconfigdeps.sh
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
 
 pkgconfig=/usr/bin/pkg-config
 test -x $pkgconfig || {

--- a/scripts/mono-find-requires
+++ b/scripts/mono-find-requires
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
--- a/scripts/mono-find-provides
+++ b/scripts/mono-find-provides
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
--- a/scripts/check-rpaths-worker
+++ b/scripts/check-rpaths-worker
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-#! /bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh

--- a/scripts/find-debuginfo.sh
+++ b/scripts/find-debuginfo.sh
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
 #find-debuginfo.sh - automagically generate debug info and file list
 #for inclusion in an rpm spec file.
 #
--- a/scripts/find-lang.sh
+++ b/scripts/find-lang.sh
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
 #findlang - automagically generate list of language specific files
 #for inclusion in an rpm spec file.
 #This does assume that the *.mo files are under .../locale/...
--- a/scripts/fontconfig.prov
+++ b/scripts/fontconfig.prov
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
--- a/scripts/check-prereqs
+++ b/scripts/check-prereqs
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
--- a/scripts/brp-python-bytecompile
+++ b/scripts/brp-python-bytecompile
@@ -1,1 +1,1 @@
-#!/bin/bash
+#!/bin/sh
```

Only the dependency checking seems to really rely on `bash` functionality, but that one didn't work anyhow, even with `bash`. Installing without dependency check works. That's okay for me.

But afterwards I found a couple of other scripts claiming to use any `/bin/sh`, but full of bashisms … *sigh*